# How do I self-host a TCP-based WCF service inside a Windows Service?

Tags: wcf, tcp, windows-services

I am trying to self-host a TCP-based WFC service inside a Windows Service. The Windows Service is a wrapper for performing 2 jobs:

1. hosting a TCP-based WCF service (note the Windows Service is a simple service)
2. running other Windows Services under it

I am able to run the Windows Service, but when trying to connect to it using a client, I get `TCP 10061: target machine actively refused connection`.

What could be missing here; why might I be getting the `TCP 10061` message?

Comment: That sounds like your firewall is blocking incoming requests. Have you opened the TCP port that you are exposing your WCF service on in your firewall?

Comment: Are you sure the port you try to connect is the port that the WCF listens?

Comment: Did you ever sole this? Im having a similar issue except mine works locally but not when the service is on another machine on the LAN. I have no firewalls running

Comment: Am having similar setup and it is working fine. Am using Setup project to install Windows Service. Could you elaborate on what setup you are using to install Windows Service. Can you see it Service Manage console and is it started.

Comment: I know this is kind of ancient, but which Account is running the service?
Please be aware that this has an impact on your functionality...

Comment: You could use netstat or TCPView (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897437.aspx) to confirm the service is listing to the correct port.
If that is the case you could check of you can reach the service locally
If that also if the case you could use wireshark to inspect the network packets